# What is the best way to deal with the project having multiple jdk compiled dependencies?

Tags: java, ant, java-7, java-5

I have an `ant` based project which was build with `Java 5`, its an old project.

Now I need to work on that again to make some changes in it. I have this other project `jar`, which is build with `Java 7` , and this `jar` needs to be added as `dependency` to the old project.

As per my understanding, I have two possibilities here:

1. Build that old project with `Java 7`
2. Build New project with `Java 5`

The 2nd options is near to impossible, as there are lot of class structure changes since `Java 5`, I have to rewrite the code almost from scratch.

The first option seems doable, but what do I need to take care of in order to build a `Java 5` project with `Java 7`, as we know there are `class structural` changes.

Note: I have tried building this old project with Java 7, it says

"`cannot access java.lang.Object bad class file: class file has wrong version 51.0, should be 49.0`"

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues. Just compile with Java 7 and see if you get any compile errors.

Comment: Have you just tried to compile it with 7 ?

Comment: I get compile errors, it says `bad class version , should be 49.0`, while building.

Comment: version `49` is from java 5, so you are building with java 5 not java 7.

Comment: @FranMontero, you are right, here is what I got:
`Detected Java version: 1.5 in: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/jre`
but I am not sure why is there java 5 ? I have tried building it with java 7 by setting javac target=1.7

Comment: the path you printed points to a run time env, not the compiler. try `which javac` to see where is the compiler

Comment: here is `which javac` output:
`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac`

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue, and I have discovered I had different java versions installed. Since I needed both, I made a script to change JAVA_HOME path on the fly.
Assuming you are on a Windows machine, firstly you need to set up enviroment variables:

- No Java-related entries in the top list ("User variables")
- JAVA_HOME = C:<Path to java installation> in the lower list ("System variables")
- Under "Path" substitute `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath` with `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
- Also add `C:\Program Files\Java\scripts` (assuming you want to place your scripts there) in order to use shortcuts to change running Java

Assuming you want a shortcut to Java7, you should create a java7.bat file and edit like this

```
@echo off
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
set Path=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%Path%
echo Java 7 activated.
```

Be careful to match java path to the actual path on your machine.
Make as many .bat files as needed (e.g. java5.bat, java7.bat) and simply type `java7` in cmd to change version.